# How can I create a simple secure login system without registration?

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I am trying to create a simple login system on my website which does not require any registration process. I will be setting the username and password for each client to use.

Basically, the idea is to have a login page that allows clients to access and view files and information (instead of using email).

The problem with the code below is that the 'username' and 'password' are hardcoded i.e easily viewed with the 'inspect element' feature.

Since I am a newbie, I was wondering if I can create a simple secure system without making use of database and php.

HTML:

```
<form name="login" class="form">
        <p class="title">Client Dashboard</p>
        <p class="login-description">This dashboard allows you to manage your project and files</p>
        <input type="text" name="userid" placeholder="Username" class="text-field"/>
        <input type="password" name="pswrd" placeholder="Password" class="text-field"/>
        <input type="submit" class="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function check(form) { /*function to check userid & password*/
            /*the following code checkes whether the entered userid and password are matching*/
            if(form.userid.value == "johnsmith" && form.pswrd.value == "password123") {
                window.open('dashboard.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
            }
            else {
                alert("Error Password or Username")/*displays error message*/
            }
        }
```

Comment: the thing is, javascript will always be visible from the browser, since it's a client script. you really need a server if you want it secure, just on my opinion

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I found this php tutorial online " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXdaXlFZLlA " but I don't know how to direct different users to different webpages.

Comment: read about header function in php

Answer (score 0):

Although this is dangerous for client side code to have login credentials, you can store user info in Array of objects then check if the array has those values.

```
var users = [{
  username: 'admin',
  password: 'abc123'
},{
  username: 'user1',
  password: '321cba'
}];

var index = users.indexof(function (user) {
  return users.username === user.username &&
  users.password === user.password;
})

if (index !== -1) {
  window.open('dashboard.html')/*opens the target page while Id & password matches*/
}
else {
  alert("Error Password or Username"
)/*displays error message*/
```